# How to detect the headphone key press?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, remote-access, headphones

I am trying to detect if user press the headphone keys for that i am using 2 methods.

```
-(void)headsetMicrophoneDetection
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(onTooglePlayPause)];

    NSLog(@"calling headset method");
}
-(void)onTooglePlayPause
{
    NSLog(@"kishore");
}
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"callig method to :)");
    if (theEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch(theEvent.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                NSLog(@"Hello");
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                NSLog(@"Hello 2");
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                NSLog(@"Hello 3");
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                NSLog(@"Hello 4");
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

But after calling this method i did't get ,whats wrong in my code and i enabled background service for audio check & i am using this all methods in NSObject class.

Comment: Are you missing : in your selector when defining selector for MPRemoteCommandCenter as the method expects a parameter?

Comment: @ldindu no i didn't missed

Comment: I would also wonder. Have you found the solution since then?

Comment: No client skipped this option later @GyörgyBenedek

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) {
        if ([[desc portType]     isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
           return YES;
    }
    return NO;}
```

Comment: but i want to check is user pressed any of the button volume ,play/pause thanks for the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try including this in `viewDidAppear`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

And this in `viewDidDisappear`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
```